# Finding contiguous regions in a 1D boolean array

Tags: python, numpy

If I have a 1D array of bools, say `np.array([True, False, True, True True, False, True, True])`, I'd like a function that could return to me the indices of all contiguous regions of `True`.

For example, the output of this function called on the above array would produce something like `[(0,0), (2,4), (6,7)]`.

I'm not sure how to accomplish this nicely, also I would like to be able to do this with PyTorch tensors as well.

Comment: Do you want only `True`, or `False` also?

Comment: It seems like it would be much more in keeping with the way Python works in other places to have half open intervals like `[(0, 1), (2, 5), (6, 8)]` which could then be used directly as ranges of slices.

Comment: @raunasur Probably don't need False just because I could easily invert the array and do the same calculation.

Comment: @Mark Good call, that might make it more user friendly. The solution I created doesn't do this but wouldn't be too hard to incorporate.

Answer (score 2):

I've implemented this exact thing in a utility library I wrote called [haggis](https://haggis.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). The function is [`haggis.npy_util.mask2runs`](https://haggis.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#haggis.npy_util.mask2runs). I wrote it in part to deal with this recurring question on Stack Overflow:

```
runs = haggis.math.mask2runs(mask)
```

The second column is exclusive indices, since that's more useful in both python and numpy, so you might want to do

```
runs[:, -1] -= 1
```

There's nothing special about this function. You can write it as a one-liner using numpy:

```
runs = numpy.flatnonzero(np.diff(numpy.r_[numpy.int8(0), mask.view(numpy.int8), numpy.int8(0)])).reshape(-1, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a near one line, numpy only implementation.

Works for the input. I have not tested for edge cases but should work as well

Cheers if you need this for Advent of Code :)

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([True, False, True, True, True, False, True, True])

#Indices are found here
a_true_ranges = np.argwhere(np.diff(a,prepend=False,append=False))

#Conversion into list of 2-tuples
a_true_ranges = a_true_ranges.reshape(len(a_true_ranges)//2,2)
a_true_ranges = [tuple(r) for r in a_true_ranges]
a_true_ranges
#[(0, 1), (2, 5), (6, 8)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution I found:

```
def find_contigs(mask):
    """
    Find contiguous regions in a mask that are True with no False in between
    """
    assert len(mask.shape) == 1 # 1D tensor of bools 
    
    contigs = []
    found_contig = False 
    for i,b in enumerate(mask):
        
        
        if b and not found_contig:   # found the beginning of a contig
            contig = [i]
            found_contig = True 
        
        elif b and found_contig:     # currently have contig, continuing it 
            pass 
        
        elif not b and found_contig: # found the end, record previous index as end, reset indicator  
            contig.append(i-1)
            found_contig = False 
            contigs.append(tuple(contig))
        
        else:                        # currently don't have a contig, and didn't find one 
            pass 
    
    
    # fence post bug - check if the very last entry was True and we didn't get to finish 
    if b:
        contig.append(i)
        found_contig = False 
        contigs.append(tuple(contig))
        
    return contigs
```

Comment: Where did you find it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's a good purely Numpy approach to this, but since it looks like you're willing to loop, you could just use `itertools.groupby` and keep track of the index and group length:

```
from itertools import groupby

a = np.array([True, False, True, True, True, False, True, True])

i = 0
res = []

for k, g in groupby(a):
    l = len(list(g))
    if k:
        res.append((i,i+l))
    i += l

print(res)
# [(0, 1), (2, 5), (6, 8)]
```

If you want the closed intervals, obviously you can just subtract 1 from the second tuple value.

You could also write it as a generator which can be a little friendlier on the memory with long lists:

```
from itertools import groupby

a = np.array([True, False, True, True, True, False, True, True])

def true_indices(a):
    i = 0
    for k, g in groupby(a):
        l = len(list(g))
        if k:
            yield (i,i+l)
        i += l

list(true_indices(a))
# [(0, 1), (2, 5), (6, 8)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with Pytorch but the problem itself looks easily solvable. You're going to want to loop over the whole list and store the first index of a contingency region where one is found. I've used -1 since it's out of bounds of any index. From there you just append a tuple to a list with the saved index and current index and reset the start index to -1. Since this relies on a False boolean being found, I've added a final check outside the loop for a non-reset start index which implies a contingency region from there to the end of the list.

I said current index but to keep it inbound I subtracted 1 to make it more in line with what you wanted.

```html
def getConRegions(booleanList):
    conRegions=[]
    start=-1
    for index,item in enumerate(booleanList):
        if item and start<0:start=index
        elif start>=0 and not item:
            conRegions.append((start,index-1))
            start=-1
    if(start>=0):conRegions.append((start,len(booleanList)-1))
    return conRegions
print(getConRegions([True,False,True,True,True,False,True,True]))
```

Answer (score 0):

**My humble solution:**

```
list = [True, False, True, True, True, False, True, True]
if list[-1] == True:
    list.extend([False])

answers = []
beginning = "yes"

for index, value in enumerate(list):
    if value == True and beginning == "yes":
        x = index
        beginning = "not anymore"
    elif value == True:
        pass
    else:
        answers.append((x, index -1))
        beginning = "yes"
        
print(answers)
```

**Output:**

```
[(0, 0), (2, 4), (6, 7)]
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Fast, numpy-based solution:

```py
import numpy as np

def find_contigs(arr):
    indices = []
    # Each number in this array will be the index of an
    # element in 'arr' just *before* it switches
    nonzeros = np.nonzero(np.diff(arr))[0]

    # Case if array begins with True
    if arr[0]:
        if len(nonzeros):
            indices.append((0, nonzeros[0] + 1))
        else:
            indices.append((0, len(arr)))
        nonzeros = nonzeros[1:]

    # Correct for array ending in True
    if len(nonzeros) % 2:
        final_idx = (nonzeros[-1] + 1, len(arr))
        nonzeros = nonzeros[:-1]
    else:
        final_idx = None

    # Parse nonzero indices
    nonzeros += 1
    nonzeros = nonzeros.reshape((len(nonzeros)//2, 2))
    indices.extend([(a, b) for a, b in zip(nonzeros[:, 0], nonzeros[:, 1])])
    if final_idx is not None:
        indices.append(final_idx)

    return indices
```